# How to generate combinations with none values in a progressive manner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate combinations (with empty values) between multiple lists in a progressive manner. For example, a=[1,2,3], b=[4,5,6], the desired output should be

```
[(1, None), (2, None), (3, None)]
[(1, 4), (2, None), (3, None)]
[(1, 5), (2, None), (3, None)]
[(1, 6), (2, None), (3, None)]
[(1, None), (2, 4), (3, None)]
[(1, None), (2, 5), (3, None)]
[(1, None), (2, 6), (3, None)]
[(1, None), (2, None), (3, 4)]
[(1, None), (2, None), (3, 5)]
[(1, None), (2, None), (3, 6)]
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, None)]
[(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, None)]
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, None)]
[(1, 4), (2, None), (3, 5)]
[(1, 4), (2, None), (3, 6)]
[(1, 5), (2, None), (3, 6)]
[(1, None), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
[(1, None), (2, 4), (3, 6)]
[(1, None), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
The number of combinations is 20
```

EDIT:
The number of results should be the sum of C(len(b),i)*C(len(a),i) for i in range(len(a)+1), meaning to choose i elements out of list "b" to be matched with i elements in list "a". In this case, 20=C(3,3)*C(3,3)+C(3,2)*C(3,2)+C(3,1)*C(3,1)+C(3,0)*C(3,0).

I've tried the code below:

```
import itertools as it

def create_combos(first, *rest):
    for index in range(len(first)+1):
        for i in it.product([first], *(it.combinations(j,index) for j in rest)):
            yield list(it.zip_longest(*i))

count=0
for combo in create_combos(a, b):
    print(combo)
    count+=1
print('The number of combinations is '+str(count))
```

However, there were only 8 combinations in the output:

```
[(1, None), (2, None), (3, None)]
[(1, 4), (2, None), (3, None)]
[(1, 5), (2, None), (3, None)]
[(1, 6), (2, None), (3, None)]
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, None)]
[(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, None)]
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, None)]
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
The number of combinations is 8
```

I think it's because the placement of numerical values is restricted. However, I couldn't think of a way to change their places without manually inserting the None values to list "b" and filtering out those unnecessary combinations, i.e. the code below:

```
import itertools as it

def create_combos(first,rest):
    clone_rest=rest[:]
    clone_rest.insert(0,None)
    for sublist in it.product(clone_rest, repeat=len(first)):
        filtered_sublist=list(filter(None,sublist))
        if len(filtered_sublist)<=1:
            yield(list(zip(first,sublist)))
        else:
            for i in range(len(filtered_sublist)-1):
                if filtered_sublist[i]>=filtered_sublist[i+1]:
                    break
            else:
                yield(list(zip(first,sublist)))

count=0
for combo in create_combos(a,b):
    print(combo)
    count+=1
print('The number of combinations is '+str(count))
```

Although this code managed to give me the output I want, it is apparently not efficient enough, especially when there are more lists and more values within each list. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you add what is the problem statement is ? like what the output tells. want to solve this problem :)

Comment: Thank you for the interest. The desired output should be able to generate all the possible combination sets, containing all the possible tuples. As you can see, the first elements of the tuples are fixed to be extracted from the "first" list (in the example, list "a"). The second elements are from the "rest" lists (in the example, list "b") and placed in a progressive/ascending manner apart from the None values, which indicates that there is no value from "b" to be matched with "a".

Comment: Why is it not efficient enough? What do you expect in terms of efficiency? Why? Is this part of a tight loop, or what is the issue?

Comment: @JohanL The problem stated here is just a very brief version of the problem I'm trying to solve. Eventually, there will be hundreds and thousands of elements in each list instead of three. In this case, it'll take a long time looping "it.product(clone_rest, repeat=len(first))" and end up producing too many redundant sublists. Thus, I'm looking for a solution that does not need the filtering process and only generate the sublist that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's take a look at what you are expecting :

What you want isn't C(6,3)=20.

Actually what you want is

C(3,i) * C(3,i) for i in [1,2,3] = 20

Why so ?

The first choice is the number of not None in your tuples, the second is the choices for the values you want to pick in those.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this. But just wanted to explain the math so everyone is on the same page

```
import itertools as it
from copy import deepcopy
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
def create_combos(a, l):
    n = len(a)
    incr = 0
    output = []
    default = [[x,None] for x in a]
    for i in range(n+1):
        choices_index = it.combinations(range(n),i)
        choices_value = list(it.combinations(l,i))
        for choice in choices_index:
            for values in choices_value:
                x = deepcopy(default)
                for index,value in zip(choice,values):
                    x[index][1] = value
                output += [x]
    print(len(output))
    print(output)



create_combos(a,b)
```

Okay now I have the same output as you , let's try to figure out a way to optimise this thing.

Comment: I agree with your math, but as it happens, `itertools.combinations()` keep the order of values, which is why my `None`-interspersed version works.

Comment: Here is the output of your code :
[[(1, None), (2, 4), (3, None)],
 [(1, None), (2, 4), (3, 5)],
 [(1, None), (2, 4), (3, None)],...
You can see there are duplicates ....

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. You are right. I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: @BornTbeWasted Thank you so much for reminding me of the math mistake! You are correct. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @BornTbeWasted Thank you! I'll try to apply this to a larger dataset and test the efficiency. In terms of optimization, I'll try to use generators (like "yield") to let the function output one combination at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If the order is not important, it should be possible to do with `itertools.combinations`:

A (somehat long) one-liner is:

```
from itertools import combinations
combo_gen = ([(1, a), (2, b), (3, c)]
             for a, b, c in combinations([None,4,None,5,None,6], 3))
```

Here every second element picked is `None` thereby allowing all types of `None`-interspersion.

Comment: You have the same problem , if you run it, you will see that the None are considered different , therefore , you have duplicates in your output

Comment: @BornTbeWasted: No, as I understand the OP this is the wanted behavior. We *want* to have 20 rows, just as I generate.

Comment: I just ran your code, it doesn't look like what OP expected.

Comment: @JohanL First of all, thank you for your answer. Actually, the prior comment is right. You can double-check my desired output. There were no duplicated rows inside. All 20 rows are different.