# How to improve the efficiency for a code involving generators and nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a code that generates a list of sublists in a progressive manner based on two numerical lists (a & b) that are both in ascending order. Each sublist, containing two elements, can be seen as a combination of elements from those two lists. The second element (from list b) is required to be larger than the first (from list a). Particularly, for the second element, the value may not always be numerical. A sublist can be [elem, None], meaning that there is no match in list b for "elem" in list a. There should not be any duplicates in the final output. If you imagine the output to be in a table, each sublist would be one row and within each of the two columns, the elements are in ascending order, apart from "None" in the second column.

I was inspired and have written a code that can achieve the objective thanks to the kind responses from my last question. ([How to generate combinations with none values in a progressive manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449335/how-to-generate-combinations-with-none-values-in-a-progressive-manner)) The code is shown here.

```py
import itertools as it
import time

start=time.time()

a=[1,5,6,7,8,10,11,13,15,16,20,24,25,27]
b=[2,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,21,26]

def create_combos(lst1, lst2): #a is the base list; l is the adjacent detector list
    n = len(lst1)
    x_ref = [None,None]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        choices_index = it.combinations(range(n),i)
        choices_value = list(it.combinations(lst2,i)) 
        for choice in choices_index:
            for values in choices_value:
                x = [[elem,None] for elem in lst1]
                for index,value in zip(choice,values): #Iterate over two lists in parallel  
                    if value <= x[index][0]:
                        x[index][0] = None
                        break
                    else:
                        x[index][1] = value #over-write in appropriate location
                if x_ref not in x:
                    yield x

count=0
combos=create_combos(a,b)
for combo in combos:
#    print(combo)
    count+=1
print('The number of combos is ',count)

end=time.time()
print('Run time is ',end-start)
```

This code is about the best I can get in terms of speed with my limited python knowledge. However, it still took too long to run as the number of elements in list a & b grows over 15. I understand it is probably because of the drastic increase in combinations. However, I wonder if any improvement can be made to increase its efficiency, perhaps regarding the way the combinations are generated. Moreover, I was generating all possible combinations and the inappropriate ones were dropped afterwards, which I assume may also be inefficient.

The desired result would be to handle about 30 elements in each list within a reasonable amount of time.

EDIT: Since once the number of elements in each list grows larger, the number of combos also increase drastically. Thus, I would like to keep the generator in order to allow only one combo to occupy the memory at a time.

Please feel free ask questions if I am unclear on any of the above statements. Thank you:)

Comment: Do not convert your combinations to a list, this is making you loose time and memory efficiency. Have you tried to do a line by line profiling also?

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I have tried to extract one combinations at a time, but it becomes not iterable when it goes down to the "for index,value in zip(choice,values):"

Comment: I feel that the list(it.combinations) is definitely taking a long time there, but without converting will cause the loss in total number of combinations.

Comment: Oh, did not see you used it twice, if you need to copy, you can use https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee, but this will not accelerate a lot. And this is a good opportunity to learn about line profiling :) This is the best way to optimize code

Comment: My problem is that what your code generates is not what your text says. For the trivial `a,b=[1,2],[3,4]`, my understanding of your requirements is that it should give `[[1,2],[1,4],[2,4]]` (only 3 sublists) while your code generates `[[[1, 2], [3, None]], [[1, 4], [3, None]], [[1, None], [3, 4]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]` (which I cannot understand)

Comment: Looking at the results of your code, it seems you generate multiple lists, each with `len(a)` pairs, with the following conditions: a) first element of each pair is from `a` and second is from `b` or `None` b) when the second element is not `None`, it must be greater than the first element c) no elements of `a` or `b` are used more than once. It also seems that the combination where all the second elements are `None` is not present in the output. Is all that correct? Does that match the output you want?

Comment: And another condition: d) each first and second element must be greater than the previous first and second elements (when not `None`).

Comment: @SergeBallesta Hi, every element from list a is allowed to be connected with None, but not all at once.

Comment: @jdehesa Hi, you are correct! There has to be at least one element that is not none.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT 2:

Okay so you can do this much faster if you just do things a bit smarter. I'm going to be using NumPy and Numba now to really accelerate things. If you don't want to use Numba it should still work by just commenting the parts where it's used, only slower. If you don't want NumPy, it could be replaced with lists or nested lists, but again probably with a significant performance difference.

So let's see. The two key things to change are:

- Preallocating the space for the output (instead of having a generator we produce the whole output at once).
- Reusing computed combinations.

To preallocate, we need to first count how many combinations we will have in total. The algorithm is similar, but just with counting, and if you have a cache for the partial counts it is actually quite fast. Numba does make a huge difference here but I already used it.

```
import numba as nb

def count_combos(a, b):
    cache = np.zeros([len(a), len(b)], dtype=np.int32)
    total = count_combos_rec(a, b, 0, 0, cache)
    return total

@nb.njit
def count_combos_rec(a, b, i, j, cache):
    if i >= len(a) or j >= len(b):
        return 1
    if cache[i][j] > 0:
        return cache[i][j]
    while j < len(b) and a[i] >= b[j]:
        j += 1
    count = 0
    for j2 in range(j, len(b)):
        count += count_combos_rec(a, b, i + 1, j2 + 1, cache)
    count += count_combos_rec(a, b, i + 1, j, cache)
    cache[i][j] = count
    return count
```

Now we can preallocate a big array for all the combinations. Instead of storing the combinations directly in there, I will have an array of integers representing the position of the element in `b` (the element in `a` is implicit by the position, and the `None` matches are represented by `-1`).

In order to reuse combinations, we do as follows. Every time we need to find the combinations for a certain pair `i`/`j`, if it has not been computed before, we do it, and then we save the position in the output array where these combinations have been stored for the first time. Next time we come across the same `i`/`j` pair, we just need to copy the corresponding part we made before.

All in all, the algorithm ends up as follows (the result in this case is a NumPy objects array, the first column being the element from `a` and the second the element from `b`, but you can use `.tolist()` to convert it to a regular Python list).

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def generate_combos(a, b):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    b = np.asarray(b)
    # Count combos
    total = count_combos(a, b)
    count_table = np.zeros([len(a), len(b)], np.int32)
    # Table telling first position of a i/j match
    ref_table = -np.ones([len(a), len(b)], dtype=np.int32)
    # Preallocate result
    result_idx = np.empty([total, len(a)], dtype=np.int32)
    # Make combos
    generate_combos_rec(a, b, 0, 0, result_idx, 0, count_table, ref_table)
    # Produce matchings array
    seconds = np.where(result_idx >= 0, b[result_idx], None)
    firsts = np.tile(a[np.newaxis], [len(seconds), 1])
    return np.stack([firsts, seconds], axis=-1)

@nb.njit
def generate_combos_rec(a, b, i, j, result, idx, count_table, ref_table):
    if i >= len(a):
        return idx + 1
    if j >= len(b):
        result[idx, i:] = -1
        return idx + 1
    elif ref_table[i, j] >= 0:
        r = ref_table[i, j]
        c = count_table[i, j]
        result[idx:idx + c, i:] = result[r:r + c, i:]
        return idx + c
    else:
        idx_ref = idx
        j_ref = j
        while j < len(b) and a[i] >= b[j]:
            j += 1
        for j2 in range(j, len(b)):
            idx_next = generate_combos_rec(a, b, i + 1, j2 + 1, result, idx, count_table, ref_table)
            result[idx:idx_next, i] = j2
            idx = idx_next
        idx_next = generate_combos_rec(a, b, i + 1, j, result, idx, count_table, ref_table)
        result[idx:idx_next, i] = -1
        idx = idx_next
        ref_table[i, j_ref] = idx_ref
        count_table[i, j_ref] = idx - idx_ref
        return idx
```

Let's check the result is still correct:

```
a = [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 20, 24, 25, 27]
b = [2, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 26]
# generate_combos_prev is the previous recursive method
combos1 = list(generate_combos_prev(a, b))
# Note we do not need list(...) here because it is not a generator
combos = generate_combos(a, b)
print((combos1 == combos).all())
# True
```

Okay good, now let's see about the performance.

```
%timeit list(generate_combos_prev(a, b))
# 3.7 s ± 17.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit generate_combos(a, b)
# 593 ms ± 2.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Nice! That is like 6x faster! The only possible downsides, besides the additional dependencies, is that we are making all the combinations at once instead of iteratively (so you will have them all at once in memory) and that we need a table for the partial counts with size O(`len(a) * len(b)`).

---

This is a faster way to do what you are doing:

```
def generate_combos(a, b):
    # Assumes a and b are already sorted
    yield from generate_combos_rec(a, b, 0, 0, [])

def generate_combos_rec(a, b, i, j, current):
    # i and j are the current indices for a and b respectively
    # current is the current combo
    if i >= len(a):
        # Here a copy of current combo is yielded
        # If you are going to use only one combo at a time you may skip the copy
        yield list(current)
    else:
        # Advance j until we get to a value bigger than a[i]
        while j < len(b) and a[i] >= b[j]:
            j += 1
        # Match a[i] with every possible value from b
        for j2 in range(j, len(b)):
            current.append((a[i], b[j2]))
            yield from generate_combos_rec(a, b, i + 1, j2 + 1, current)
            current.pop()
        # Match a[i] with None
        current.append((a[i], None))
        yield from generate_combos_rec(a, b, i + 1, j, current)
        current.pop()

a = [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 20, 24, 25, 27]
b = [2, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 26]
count = 0
combos = generate_combos(a, b)
for combo in combos:
    count += 1
print('The number of combos is', count)
# 1262170
```

The only difference with this algorithm is that it generates one more combination than yours (in your code the final count is 1262169), namely one where every element in `a` is matched with `None`. This is always the last combination to be generated, so you can just ignore that one if you want.

EDIT: If you prefer, you can move the `# Match a[i] with None` block in `generate_combos_rec` to just between the `while` loop and the `for` loop, and then the extra combination with every value in `a` matched to `None` will be the first one instead of the last one. That may make it easier to skip it. Alternatively, you can replace `yield list(current)` with:

```
if any(m is not None for _, m in current):
    yield list(current)
```

To avoid generating the extra combination (at the expense of an additional inspection of every generated combination).

EDIT 2:

Here is a slightly modified version that avoids the extra combination by just carrying a boolean indicator in the recursion.

```
def generate_combos(a, b):
    yield from generate_combos_rec(a, b, 0, 0, [], True)

def generate_combos_rec(a, b, i, j, current, all_none):
    if i >= len(a):
        if not all_none:
            yield list(current)
    else:
        while j < len(b) and a[i] >= b[j]:
            j += 1
        for j2 in range(j, len(b)):
            current.append((a[i], b[j2]))
            yield from generate_combos_rec(a, b, i + 1, j2 + 1, current, False)
            current.pop()
        current.append((a[i], None))
        yield from generate_combos_rec(a, b, i + 1, j, current, all_none)
        current.pop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! The speed has definitely been faster! I can keep the all-none combo for a faster speed. Thanks again!

Comment: The first version of code with the "# Match a[i] with None block" moved to front has the shortest run time so far. I will try it out with more data for comparison.

Comment: Hi, I tried the code with my actual data (float type) with 18 data in list a and 17 data in list b. The number of combos is 1,289,624,490 and it takes 66 minutes to run. Do you think it is the fastest we can get for processing such number of combos?

Comment: @MollyZhou Okay, so I _finally_ was able to put it together. The new algorithm I put is much faster than the previous one I posted, which was already faster than the original one. Give that a try and see how it goes. Note in this case the whole output is produce at once, instead of iteratively.

Comment: @MollyZhou Oh I see from your previous comment that you are trying to produce 1,289,624,490 combinations... that may be too much to generate in a non-iterative way! I mean it will take gigabytes of memory. You can replace the huge arrays with `memmap`ed ones, but still...

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Since there is another computation based on each combo following this part of the code, I was using the generator to save time and mostly memory and allow the combos to be computed one at a time.

Comment: In other words, I don't really need to memorize all the combos, which is also impossible. I was only trying to generate them as fast as I can and do the following computation for each combo. The follow-up computation is quite fast, so I assume the generation of combo should be a key to speed up the process. I will look into your code and see if I can revise it to generators. Thank you again:)

Comment: I tried to convert the output to a generator by letting it iterate over "firsts" and "seconds" at the end of "generate_combos" function and yield one combo at a time. It appeared to be slower than your previous version.